# Why does the C++ sort() function not work in the sort(vectorname) form whereas it works as sort(vectorname.begin(), vectorname.end())?

Tags: c++, sorting

Could anybody explain why the `std::sort()` function doesn't work when the name of the vector is placed inside the brackets, e.g. `sort(vectorname)`, and instead gives out a compiler error message:

```
  dictionary.cpp:20:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘sort(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)’
  sort(words);
```

whereas it works OK if it is written in the form `sort(vectorname.begin, vectorname.end)`?

Here are the details:

```
/* This is a dictionary program which is intended to
(1) read in separate words typed in the command line,
(2) sort them, and 
(3) output them alphabetacally.
I am asking about lines #25 and #26.
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;

    for(string word; cin>>word;) {
        words.push_back(word);
    }

    cout<<"Number of words: "<<words.size()<<'\n';

    //sort(words.begin(), words.end()); //This method works ok
    sort(words);//But this one doesn't work

    for(int i=0; i<words.size(); ++i) {
        if(i==0 || words[i-1]!=words[i]) {
            cout<<words[i]<<'\n';
        }
    }
}
```

This is on Ubuntu 15.10 OS, using the g++ 5.2.1 compiler.

Comment: Because `std::sort` doesn't have an overload that takes a container.  `std::sort` deals with a iterator range like almost all of the other standard algorithms.  I suggest you consult the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: Just about all [C++ standard algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) takes a *range*. What if, for example, you only want to sort a *part* of a container? Or sort something that isn't a standard container but have suitable iterators? Better have a generic function than many overloads that all does basically the same thing.

Comment: No need to downvote or close the question. The question 'why sort doesn't have a container overload, which would save on typing and actually be safer on many cases' is a valid question.

Comment: Its because it needs to know how far you want to take it. Remember this is c++ and you have lots of control what you want to do.  Also what NathanOliver said.

Comment: @NathanOliver and JoachimPileborg, thank you for the references.

Answer (score 3):

When you call a C++ function you pass it arguments. The `std::sort` function works on a "range" of elements, and in C++ today you specify a range by a pair of "iterators" which denote the beginning and end of the range. So in C++ today a range is not a single object, it's a conceptual thing described by two objects.

This is a very flexible design, as it allows `std::sort` to work with *any* range that can be described by a pair of iterators denoting the beginning and end (e.g. you can sort just the first half of a container by passing iterators pointing to the beginning and the middle of the container, or you can sort an array by passing pointers to the beginning and end of the array). So to call `std::sort` you need to pass two arguments, which must be iterators describing the range you want to sort.

But that flexibility comes at the cost of convenience: if you have an object that contains a range of elements, such as `vectorname`, it's a single argument, not two iterator arguments, so you can't pass it to `std::sort`. Instead you call the `begin()` and `end()` member functions to get a pair of iterators from it.

However, there are changes being planned for C++ to specify new versions of the standard algorithms, including `sort`, which work with a single object that describes a range. So in future you'll be able to represent a range as either a pair of iterators describing the range, or a single object which represents a range directly.

Comment: For any pedants: yes, of course for `std::sort`, those do have to be random access iterators, not just *any* possible pair of iterators.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: "because `std::sort` is defined to receive a pair of iterators, not a container."

The slightly snarky answer is: 'because you included `<algorithm>` instead of [`"boost/range/algorithm/sort.hpp"`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/sort.html)'.

A better (but still a little snarky) answer would be 'because you included `<algorithm>` instead of [`"range/v3/algorithm"`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)'.

Snark aside, I really would recommend looking at Eric Neibler's range library if you don't like explicitly passing `begin()` and `end()` iterators for things like this. Even if you don't mind that particular bit of syntax, I'd recommend looking at it anyway--I think it's a well thought out design, and it's well on its way toward being included in some future version of the C++ standard.

Comment: Do you know if there are still plans for this to go into the language? :)

Comment: @Zorglub29 It's in the draft for C++20, which has been approved by the committee, and is in its last steps toward becoming the official standard.

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort` works on ranges (specified by iterators), so it needs a place to start and end. It doesn't have to sort the entire container. The way it is specified is simply the most general way.

You can read the details over at cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Or read the standard if you want more detail: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4582.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Ranges are not a part of the standard C++ library yet. More details at [CppCon 2015: Eric Niebler "Ranges for the Standard Library"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFUXNMfaciE).

However, you can use [Boost Range library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html), specifically [`boost::sort`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/sort.html).

Answer (score 1):

I find it to be defect in `std::sort`. Yes, you **do** need an iterator-taking version of it (to be able to sort subranges of containers, or dynamic arrays).

However, it could as well have an overload which takes the container and obtains iterator from it.

Comment: And it's going to, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4569.pdf

Comment: isnt it by design, that algorithms work on iterators instead of containers to be more generic?

Comment: @tobi303, designs are not decendent upon us from gods, people come up with them. And sometimes designs could be improved.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, sure. But you don't really need the powerful ranges for simple sort overload. It could be done in 1998, could be done 2003, could be done in 2011 or 2014.

Comment: @SergeyA Hurb Sutter has a nice article on part of the reason iterators were used: http://herbsutter.com/2011/10/07/why-no-container-based-algorithms/

Comment: if you ask a creationist he may have a different opinion ;) Of course you are right, I was just referring to the original reasoning that lead to the current design. That it can be improved is out of question

Comment: @NathanOliver, i am aware of this. It still could be done.